# Drop shadow on a TextView on Android

Tags: java, android

I have a TextView which has border on LEFT, RIGHT and BOTTOM as you can see the following:
[image]

The XML code for that is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#D30308" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="5dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">  
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFE5E5" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Is there any way to drop a shadow to the right and bottom border like this to make it look like it's floating:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was waiting to see if anyone else would answer this with with something that I don't know yet, perhaps they will however I will answer with what I know.  You could do the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FFE5E5" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- 95dp assumes the width is 100 -->
<!-- Left side gradient -->
<item android:right="95dp" android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape android:dither="true">
        <gradient android:angle="180"
                  android:endColor="#00333333"
                  android:startColor="#ff333333"
                  android:type="linear"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Right side gradient -->
<item android:left="95dp" android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape android:dither="true">
        <gradient android:angle="0"
                  android:endColor="#00333333"
                  android:startColor="#ff333333"
                  android:type="linear"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Bottom gradient -->
<!-- To prevent overlap we set 10dp on left and right -->
<item android:top="95dp" android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp">
    <shape android:dither="true">
        <gradient android:angle="270"
                  android:endColor="#00333333"
                  android:startColor="#ff333333"
                  android:type="linear"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Creates the left-corner gradient -->
<item android:top="95dp" android:right="95dp">
    <shape android:dither="true">
        <gradient android:gradientRadius="15"
                  android:centerX="1"
                  android:centerY="0"
                  android:endColor="#00333333"
                  android:startColor="#ff333333"
                  android:type="radial"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Create the right-corner gradient -->
<item android:top="95dp" android:left="95dp">
    <shape android:dither="true">
        <gradient android:gradientRadius="15"
                  android:centerX="0"
                  android:centerY="0"
                  android:endColor="#00333333"
                  android:startColor="#ff333333"
                  android:type="radial"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

There are two problems with this that make it un-reasonable.

1. The gradientRadius value is not a dip value, therefore scaling to different screen sizes would make the corners be incorrect sizes.
2. The amounts (95dp) used to get to the right, and bottom gradients means that the size has to be known at development time and cannot be resized.

The best way that I can think of performing the drop shadow that you want would be to subclass the TextView and override the onDraw() function and manually draw the gradients similar to what I have in the xml above.

for example: (**UPDATED**)

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //Gets the pixel size from dp (5)
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        final int gradientWidth = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 5, metrics);

        final int startColor =  0x00333333;
        final int endColor =    0xff333333;

        Rect clip = new Rect();
        getDrawingRect(clip);
        int saveNumber = canvas.save(Canvas.CLIP_SAVE_FLAG);

        //Set a smaller clip rect (drawing area) so that the original background gets drawn, and our drop shadow isn't put on top
        canvas.clipRect(new Rect(clip.left + gradientWidth, clip.top + gradientWidth, clip.right - gradientWidth, clip.bottom - gradientWidth), Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Return to the original clip rect
        canvas.restoreToCount(saveNumber);


        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        //The left gradient
        LinearGradient leftGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, gradientWidth, 0, startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(leftGradient);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, gradientWidth, getHeight() - gradientWidth, paint);

        //The right gradient
        LinearGradient rightGradient = new LinearGradient(getWidth() - gradientWidth, 0, getWidth(), 0, endColor, startColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(rightGradient);
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - gradientWidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() - gradientWidth, paint);

        //The bottom gradient
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(270, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
        int nX = (getWidth()/2) - (getHeight()/2);
        int nY = 0 - ((getWidth()/2) - (getHeight()/2));

        LinearGradient bottomGradient = new LinearGradient(nX, nY, nX + gradientWidth, nY, startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(bottomGradient);
        canvas.drawRect(nX, nY + gradientWidth, nX + gradientWidth, nY + getWidth() - gradientWidth, paint);
        canvas.restore();



        //Draw the bottom-left corner
        int doubleWidth = 2*gradientWidth;
        LinearGradient leftCorner = new LinearGradient(0, 0, gradientWidth, 0, startColor, endColor, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(leftCorner);

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(doubleWidth, doubleWidth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas bCanvas = new Canvas(b);
        bCanvas.save();
        bCanvas.rotate(315, doubleWidth/2, doubleWidth/2);

        RectF leftCornerRect = new RectF(0, 0, doubleWidth, doubleWidth);
        bCanvas.drawArc(leftCornerRect, 135, 90, true, paint);
        bCanvas.restore();

        canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, getHeight() - doubleWidth, null);


        //Draw the bottom-right corner
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(270);
        Bitmap b2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(b, 0, 0, b.getWidth(), b.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        canvas.drawBitmap(b2, getWidth()-doubleWidth, getHeight()-doubleWidth, null);
    }
```

which can then be implemented in xml (with modifying the path to be correct) with:

```
<com.so.SO_Questions.Views.SO_TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#7799cc"
            android:text=""/>
```

There is still a few issues with this since I don't have the time to smooth them out at the moment.  The main two are the corner gradients don't match exactly so they will need some tweaking, and the clipRect isn't working like I expect it to so the background color is coming through.

If you have any questions or need some more help let me know.  Also, if you get either of the issues with the onDraw resolved let me know and I will update my answer, or you can add it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for responding. What if I used `@dimen\` for the DP for different resolution screens? Wuoldn't combining the XML make it easier? How would I go on about implementing the java code in my program?

Comment: See my edits above.  Also, using @dimen would only obfuscate the issue, you would still be unable to use DP.  As far as combining the XML's goes, you could combine them it is just a preference, the sizing issue (95dp) would still be there.